# funcion mail para el envio de correos y no SMTP

Tags: php, formularios

tengo un problema, he realizado este script con php para el envío de la información de formualrios y me dicen desde 1&1 que el protocolo SMTP puede dar problemas en su servidor, mientras que la función mail sí funciona, y me envían esta plantilla para configurarlo con un archivo mail.htt que refleja la entrada del formulario y otro response.htt para agradecer si el envío ha sido exitoso.

La plantilla que me manda 1&1 del HTML es esta:

¿cómo puedo incrustar la información de cada campo de mi formnulario en la plantilla que me manda 1&1 y que asegura sí funciona? Veo que la plantilla HTML del formulario lleva type="hidden" y no sé cómo realizarlo, esto no se parece en nada a lo que veo en tutoriales que a todo el mundo parece funcionar.

Gracias,

Un saludo.

Comment: La función `mail` (nativa de PHP) es para cosas muy básicas, como envío de correos llanos o a lo sumo con texto HTML. En cambio si pretendes cosas más avanzadas como envío de archivos adjuntos u otras la mejor opción es `PHPMailer`. Pero esta biblioteca no es nativa de PHP y puede que no esté instalada en tu entorno remoto. Ese es el motivo, según creo, por el que no funciona en tu hosting. Puedes hacer dos cosas: 1. Instalar PHPMailer en tu entorno remoto (mediante `composer` es relativamente fácil) o 2. Usar `mail` en cuyo caso tendrás que basar todo el código en `mail` no en `PHPMailer`.

Comment: Hola, tengo muchas dificultades por ser usuaria MAC (mojave) para instalar composer (parece ser que la nueva politica de proteccion de la empresa no permite la instlación de librerias desde la consola). He subido todos los archivos del src de PHPMailer al servidor remoto, pero no funciona. Desde mi local va como la seda, pero desde el hosting no va y me dicen que el protocolo SMTP no está aconsejado, cuando el propio PHPMailer es como aconseja configurarlo.

Comment: Pero cuando hablo de instalar PHPMailer me refiero al sitio remoto, no a tu dispotivo local (MAC Mojave). Son dos cosas distintas. Si en local te funciona es porque ya tienes PHPMailer, el problema es en remoto (en tu hosting) es ahí donde tendrías que instalar PHPMailer con `composer` o subiendo todos los archivos a mano desde GitHub. Para eso lo mejor es que entres por ssh a tu hosting e instales usando composer. Si te suena a chino averigua primero porque la entrada vía ssh es delicada, debes saber lo que estás haciendo porque podrías borrar archivos o desconfigurar el sitio remoto.

Comment: Tengo copiados los archivos de PHPMailer en mi servidor remoto a mano, sin composer. Copy Paste de los cinco archivos del src en una carpeta en el directorio de mi proyecto bajo el nombre PHPMailer. Creo que con el require de la cabecera de mi archivo php, es suficiente, ¿o no? ta mando el enlace donde encontré lo de la nueva politica de proteccion de mac marc.vos.net/howto/phpmailer

Comment: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899 en este enlace de Mac está más detallado

Comment: Pero es que eso no tiene nada que ver con Mac, cuando envías un email desde el servidor remoto, se usa el servidor remoto para enviarlo, no tu Mac. O sea que si desde China alguien entra al formulario de tu servidor remoto que envía el email éste se enviará, aún el chino esté conectado desde una máquina de escribir [LOL], un Windows, un Mac, un Linux o lo que sea. Del envío del email se encarga el servidor en ese caso, no el cliente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sí la funcion mail() te aseguran desde 1&1 que funciona correctamente, tan solo tienes que quitar la parte de configuración SMTP de tu llamada a phpmailer, sobre todo el `$mail->isSMTP();`

```
//Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;                                 // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->CharSeT = 'UTF-8';
    $mail->Username = 'elcallejondelagata@gmail.com';                 // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = '';                           // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 587;
```

con comentar esa parte del código eso debería de valer.

Comment: funciona, pero me da la advertencia de que puede ser suplantacion de indentidad o spam.